# Creating View from Local Variable

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create a view from below code as is?

```
Declare @colPivot varchar(Max)
Select @colPivot = STUFF((Select Distinct TOP 100 Percent ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),RTRIM(LTRIM(t2.FieldID))) + 'PreValue')
                From [dbo].[tbldocument] as t2 Inner join [dbo].[tbldocument] as t3 on t3.DocumentID=t2.DocumentID 
                where t2.BatchClassID=t3.BatchClassID
                Order by ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),RTRIM(LTRIM(t2.FieldID))) + 'PreValue')
                For xml path(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

Print @colPivot

Declare @query varchar(Max)

Set @query = 'Select * From (Select

                            [DocumentID],
                            [ClassID],
                            [PreValue],
                            convert(varchar(255),[FieldID]) + ''PreValue'' as Fieldwise

                            From 
                                [TestDB].[dbo].[tbldocument]
                            )A
            Pivot(max([PreValue]) For Fieldwise  IN ('+ @colPivot +'))p'

PRINT (@query)
Exec (@query)
```

I have 5 more such code blocks, each returning 4 columns, for which I would want to create view for each, so that I could join all 6 views and get a common result for 4*6 columns.

I tried putting above code block in Create View statement, it had thrown errors.

thanks, Inder

Comment: no you can't. this is dynamic sql e cannot be put in a view.

Comment: You can't do this as a view. A view is a single query, it can't have t-sql logic, it can't execute anything and you can't have dynamic sql. You would have to do this as a stored procedure instead.

Comment: Thanks Sean Lange.  Could you please help with some example how would this be achievable using stored procedure? Because the final output has to be all the column from such 6 code blocks. Would it require 6 stored procedures? or just one would be able to return final result set? Or will it be possible to use CTEs to do this?

Comment: google and learn about the CREATE PROCEDURE statement in sql server.